# Sorting a databound dropdownlist

Tags: c#, sharepoint, drop-down-menu

I'm new to C# and I'm having a little trouble sorting a dropdown list that's bound to a SharePoint list. 
The dropdown seems to be ordered by the created date of each item in the sharepoint list, I need it sorted by title. 
Whats the easiest way to do this?

Thanks!

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SPList list = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["Services"];

        //DataTable dt = list.Items.GetDataTable();
        //dt.Rows.


        DropDownList2.DataSource = list.Items.GetDataTable();
        DropDownList2.DataTextField = "Title";
        DropDownList2.DataBind();
        Image1.Visible =  false;

        DropDownList2.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
        this.DropDownList2.Items.Insert(0, "-Select-");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to a previous answer at [Sorting List Items (Latest one first)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894721/sorting-list-items-latest-one-first)

```
SPList list = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["Services"];
SPQuery q = new SPQuery();
q.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title'/></OrderBy>";
SPListCollection listItemCollection = list.GetItems(q);
```

Also MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms457534(v=office.15).aspx for more information about `SPQuery`

Or if you can sort it with linq, **not tested** which should return an `IEnumerable<YourServiceClass>`

```
list.OrderBy(service => service.Title);
```